# How to rewrite a column based off of two different groups

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a data frame that has many rows like this:

```
 subject-id activity label    timestamp          x         y          z
1       1600              A 2.522077e+14 -0.3647613  8.793503  1.0550842
2       1600              A 2.522077e+14 -0.8797302  9.768784  1.0169983
3       1600              A 2.522078e+14  2.0014954 11.109070   2.619156
4       1600              A 2.522078e+14  0.4506226 12.651642 0.18455505
5       1600              A 2.522079e+14 -2.1643524 13.928436 -4.4224854
6       1600              A 2.522079e+14 -4.3327790 13.361191 -0.7188721
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label    timestamp           x          y          z
991      1600             B 2.519876e+14  1.37554930 15.3750460  2.9716187
992      1600             B 2.519877e+14 -3.93443300 17.5387880  2.1100159
993      1600             B 2.519877e+14 -0.08773804 12.7915650 -1.4541016
994      1600             B 2.519878e+14  2.03874200  3.0771484 -1.0537262
995      1600             B 2.519878e+14 -2.55847170 -2.7386780 -2.0985107
996      1600             B 2.519879e+14 -1.35530090  0.3884125 -0.6598511
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label timestamp          x         y           z
24551       1601              A  12865.64  4.7034090  9.127296  0.06404489
24552       1601              A  12865.68  5.3546320 15.635334 -0.62907650
24553       1601              A  12865.72  6.3997010 12.926893  0.45010993
24554       1601              A  12865.76 10.5320930 13.207614 -1.02471830
24555       1601              A  12865.80 16.1297360  2.683301  1.14263270
24556       1601              A  12865.84  0.3932476  6.549937 -3.78224020
```

How can I set the time equal to zero by group "subject-id" and "activity label" and then increments 0.05 to the rest of the group as I move down the rows. Like this:

```
  subject-id activity label    timestamp          x         y          z
1       1600              A            0 -0.3647613  8.793503  1.0550842
2       1600              A          .05 -0.8797302  9.768784  1.0169983
3       1600              A          .10  2.0014954 11.109070   2.619156
4       1600              A          .15  0.4506226 12.651642 0.18455505
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label    timestamp           x          y          z
991      1600             B            0  1.37554930 15.3750460  2.9716187
992      1600             B          .05 -3.93443300 17.5387880  2.1100159
993      1600             B          .10 -0.08773804 12.7915650 -1.4541016
.
.
.
  subject-id activity label timestamp          x         y           z
24551       1601              A         0  4.7034090  9.127296  0.06404489
24552       1601              A       .05  5.3546320 15.635334 -0.62907650
24553       1601              A       .10  6.3997010 12.926893  0.45010993
```

I have been trying to use the dplyr function because I tend to be unsuccessful with loops in the long run. I have tried the following but I can't figure out what the argument for mutate should be:

```
test <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(`activity label`, `subject-id`) %>% mutate(timestamp = ???))
```

Should I not be using mutate()? Should I use do()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq` to create sequence starting from 0 with steps of 0.05 with length as number of rows in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(`activity label`, `subject-id`) %>%
  mutate(timestamp = seq(0, by = 0.05, length.out = n()))
```

`n()` gives number of rows, since our data is grouped here it gives number of rows in each group.

Comment: That worked great! Except, I have no idea what length.out = n() means. Care to explain?

Comment: Updated the answer explaining `n()`.

Comment: I see, that is what I was missing (I tried seq() before and I couldn't get it to output the correct length)! That creates a lot of new ideas for me. Thank you!